etable does not work properly in rmarkdown: table does not show up when plot a graph before
I am making a beamer presentation using feols regressions and etable command. I need the latex command adjustbox to fit a table on the page, but when I use it and plot a graph before, the table does not show up. The reproducible example is below.
---
title: "Teste"
output: beamer_presentation
date: "2024-11-14"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  - \usepackage{wrapfig}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{colortbl}
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
  - \usepackage{tabu}
  - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
  - \usepackage{makecell}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{adjustbox}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(fixest)
library(tidyverse)
library(tinytex)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r pressure}
pressure%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=temperature,y=pressure))+
  geom_point()
```

## Slide with R Output

```{r cars, results = 'asis'}
ols=feols(speed~dist,data=cars)

etable(ols,ols,ols,ols,ols,ols,style.tex = style.tex(adjustbox = T),postprocess.df = pandoc.table.return,tex=T)
```

You can try and you will see that the table will not appear unless we take out the graph before. This is very strange, I do not understand why this is happening. Maybe a bug regarding the convertion to latex.
I would like any help.

I found out how to display the table, following the answer to this question. Just add
- \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio} 

to the header.
